# PHP curl_multi_getcontent partial body received

Tags: php, apache, curl, curl-multi

I'm struggling on this problem.

The body I am fetching is not a big one, 3100 chars. Apache logs on the server says the content length was 3100. However, the string returned by curl_multi_getcontent was cut to 1290 characters.

Usually curl_multi_getcontent() works fine, but sometimes we get this weird behaviour.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your source code?  See http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code was missing the check for transfers in progress.

With transfers in progress:

> ```
> http_code = 200
> errno = 0
> download_content_length = total length, e.g. 1M
> size_download = current position, <= download_content_length
> ```

Seems the while( curlm_multi_exec == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM ) is somewhat insufficient.
We have to loop with usleep until sizes match for this url or multi_exec second argument announces all urls finished.

Steps to reproduce:

- PHP < 5.2, One url with transfer time of several seconds.

Comment: For websites without Content-Length there is no size to match. Monitoring transfer time seems working option.

Answer (score 1):

This one kicked my butt. It seems to be a bug in php5's (multi?)curl system. I encountered this bug while using the rolling-curl multicurl lib, but the underlying problem seems to be in php itself. Here's my php -v:

```
PHP 5.3.3-1ubuntu9.3 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Jan 12 2011 16:07:38) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
```

Under some circumstances (in my case CURLOPT_TIMEOUT was being maxed) curl_error and curl_errno would not properly report an error in the curl. I had to use the 'result' key from the array returned by curl_multi_info_read. That result code gave me the actual error number when the curl_err* functions reported everything as normal.

I think this problem is related to this bug report: http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52558